# Is GlobalMemoryStatusEx thread safe?

Tags: c++, windows, thread-safety

From the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366589%28VS.85%29.aspx):

"The information returned by the GlobalMemoryStatusEx function is volatile. There is no guarantee that two sequential calls to this function will return the same information."

This makes sense, however I cannot determine if this is thread safe or not. Does anybody know one way or another for sure? I have tried Googling this but cannot find this information.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'thread safe' in this context?? It looks as this is a kernel function call and will block the caller thread until the result is fetched and returned.

Comment: No program state is going to be corrupted when you call this function from multiple threads.  It is just trying to warn you that the info you get back is instantly stale.  It is a code smell.

Comment: Can I safely call it from multiple concurrent threads and rely on the results to be reasonably accurate? Edit: With the fact that the results will be instantly stale in mind.

Comment: @KSletmoe So you can't rely on getting same results for subsequent calls, even if they are subsequent because of thread scheduling. That's what the documentation says. What _'reasonably accurate'_ means, you'll have to decide yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What the MSDN page states is that the information returned by the function changes in time: this is what "volatile" means. For example, the information returned by `GetSystemTime` is also "volatile".

Other different concepts on procedures are "being re-entrant" and "being thread-safe". Being re-entrant means that the information used by the procedure relies on local variables, not global ones, which may be interpreted as a form of thread-safe procedure. However, "thread-safe" means that the procedure implements mechanisms of thread mutual exclusion when accessing to the resources required by the procedure.

Now, although MSDN doesn't say anything about the function to be thread-safe, provided that it accesses to system resources we may assume the function is actually thread-safe. Furthermore, the function takes a pointer to a local struct (in which the function writes the information) so it is reentrant. If `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` returned a pointer to a global structure, then we could suspect the function is not thread-safe. In such case people from MS would probably notice this. For instance, see the final note on the Remarks section of this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8d19sb(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks, this answer as well as the comments on my question answered what I wanted to know.